# Question regarding Bayes rule

Tags: probability

I know that Bayes rule states
$P(X|Y) = P(X  and  Y)/ P(Y)$

What happens if P(X|X>=Y)?
Will I divide by marginal probability of Y or P(X>=Y). For instance how would I approach problem given following PMF

```
X/Y          1            4
1            0.018        0.153
2            0.045        0.18
5            0.235        0.369
```

Comment: As written this doesn't make sense.  To have the notation $P(X|Y)$ be meaningful, you need $X$ and $Y$ to be events, but to have $X > Y$ you need $X$ and $Y$ to be random variables.  Do you have a particular problem you're interested in?

Comment: Yes, I am talking about random variables here.

Comment: $P(X>Y)$ can be expressed as $1-P(X<Y)$, which is $1-F(x)$ where $ F$ is cdf of $Y$.

Comment: @DavidS So how would the entire formula look like ?

Comment: @MichaelLugo I have added the problem

Comment: What you cite as "the Bayes rule" is instead actually the definition of conditional probability (a closely related formula, to be sure).  One can appy that "PMF" (probability mass function) data for the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ to evaluate any well-formulated conditional probability.  But if $X$ is a random variable, so that typically an outcome is a real number (about which one might ask whether $X\gt Y$), one does not say "What is $P(X)$?", the probability of $X$.  You are perhaps asking about expected values of random variables (conditioned on $X\gt Y$)?

Comment: @hardmath yes!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the formula

$$ P(A | B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$$

$A$ and $B$ are, to start with, *events* (of which $B$ must have non-zero probability).  By a slight abuse of notation, we write the same when $X,Y$ are *random variables*.

$$ P(Y | X) = \frac{P(X\cap Y)}{P(X)}$$

but here the events are to be understood as the particular values that each variable can take . That is, by $P(X)$ we mean $P(X=x)$, and so on. This can also be generalized to continuous variables, using densities. All this is explained in the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem#Forms).

The expression $P(X|X \ge Y)$ has no problem, you just need to remember that the condition is an event. If you feel unsure, write it more explicitly:

$$P(X=x|X \ge Y)=\frac{P(X=x \cap X \ge Y)}{P(X \ge Y)}$$

From your table, the numerator and denominator should be easily computable, by summing the corresponding terms.

This should also make you clear that $P(X|Y)$ depends on two variables (in your example, you should compute $6$ values, while $P(X|X \ge Y)$ depends only on $X$ (you must compute $3$ values)

Comment: Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Please answer one last question. I am just confirming here. P(X=1 | X=1 >= Y) = (0.171 * 0.018)/ 0.018. Given that P(x=1) = 0.171. Is this correct? Repeating the same process for every x and then adding it up

Comment: No, that's wrong. Remeber, The denominator (the condition) is a plain event, it does not depend on the value of $x$!.

Comment: $P(X=1 \cap X \ge Y) = 0.018$ , $P(X\ge Y)=0.018+0.045+0.235+0.369$

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks again!

Comment: @hardmath Fixed. thanks.